# How to find out where a window is located on a desktop with swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I'm trying to make a swing application that whenever you click a button it transfers from one jframe to another seamlessly.

This is what code I'm using currently to hide one jframe and display the other

```
private void switch() {
    this.setVisible(false);
    new Register().setVisible(true);
}
```

NOW HERE'S THE PROBLEM:
lets say the person drags the window to the center of the screen, whenever the above method is called the register jframe would open on the left hand corner, and the current open jframe would hide itself. How would I make it open where the previous jframe was. Also if there is a better way to do what I'm attempting please inform me.

Comment: Assuming you have a reference to the current window you can use getLocation to the windows location on the screen and use this value and pass it to the new windows setLocation method. Equally, you could use setLocationRealtiveTo, passing the old window as the component reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use in the second JFrame:

```
setLocationRelativeTo(firstJFrame);
```

Or you could use

```
setLocation(firstJFrame.getLocation());
```